# Is there a way to change the order/way Acrobat selects text of a PDF?

Tags: vba, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a visual basic program that extracts text from a PDF and imports the text into excel. It relies on reading the text like a human, reading left to right across the page. However, there are instances on this particular PDF where if I go to select the text with my mouse, I click and drag straight across but Adobe starts to select/highlight words on the above and below lines before continuing to highlight across the page. This gives me data that I do not want/need. The page has renderable text and is not from a scanned document.

Is there a way to "reset" the way Adobe interprets the text on the PDF? Since the information on the left is far from the information on the right, it treats them almost like separate columns.

I've tried saving the PDF in different formats such as a txt or postscript and distilling to another PDF but they all seem to result in the same outcome. This is weird to me because I have other similar PDFs where this isn't an issue.

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Add your code what you have tried till now

Answer (score 0):

As PDF (in its basic form) essentially means placing strings on a canvas, the concept of "sentence" or "reading order" is not built in.

In order to extract text, you would have to read out the bounding box of the piece of text, and then use some logic and heuristics to assemble your text based on the coordinates of the bounding box.

Things can be easier if the PDF is a structured PDF, where the text contents is embedded as text in the document. This is also the prime requirement for an accessible document. So, if your document is accessible, you can rely on the structure for the correct reading order.

Comment: Usually the structure of the PDF is the same and is accessible. But this one was edited (I'm not sure the method they used) and it has changed the structure of the document on only a few lines. So I was curious if there was a way to "correct" the structure. For example, when I save the document as a .txt(plain) document, some of the lines are corrected and the structure is repaired. However, not all of them are. Hence my problem. Thank you for your response Max.